# Blazor Server: EditForm requires Model or EditContext, but Model is specified

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I created a form with using EditForm:

```
<EditForm Model="@LoginEmployee" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit" FormName="login_employee" novalidate>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <FluentValidationSummary />

    <FluentStack style="height: 100vh" Orientation="Orientation.Vertical" VerticalAlignment="VerticalAlignment.Center" HorizontalAlignment="HorizontalAlignment.Center">
        <h3>Login</h3>
        <FluentTextField @bind-Value="LoginEmployee.Login">Login</FluentTextField>
        <FluentTextField @bind-Value="LoginEmployee.Password" TextFieldType="TextFieldType.Password">Password</FluentTextField>
        <FluentButton Type="ButtonType.Submit" Appearance="Appearance.Accent">Submit</FluentButton>
    </FluentStack>
    
    <FluentMessageBarProvider Section="MESSAGES_TOP" />
    @*<FluentMessageBar Title="Error" Type="MessageType.Notification" Intent="MessageIntent.Error" Visible="false"/>*@
</EditForm>
```

However, it still throws an exception: EditForm requires either a Model parameter, or an EditContext parameter, please provide one of these.

Blazor code part looks like that:

```
@code {
    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private LoginEmployeeCommand LoginEmployee { get; set; } = new();

    //...other code
}
```

Page rendered on server, not interactive.

Comment: `LoginEmployee` must be `null` when you render the form, therefore `SupplyParameterFromForm` is setting  the parameter to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the error in .net8. It seems we have to use `<InputText...` component for `EditForm`. So I tried add a hidden `<InputText>` inside the form and the error disappears.

```
...
    <InputText type="hidden" @bind-Value="LoginEmployee.Login"></InputText>  //meaningless hidden inputext
    <FluentTextField @bind-Value="LoginEmployee.Login">Login</FluentTextField>
...
```

Comment: It seems that it's a bug of Fluent UI Blazor, because it assigns login value from hidden InputText, not FLuentTextField.